# RavenDB - when to use AbstractIndexCreationTask Index, Sort and Store methods?

Tags: indexing, lucene, ravendb, lucene.net

Somehow revendb official documentation haven't answered on this question.

I've created my own index and definded Map function. Do i need also to add mentioned fields in Index, Sort or Store methods? As i understood, i need to add Sort call if i want to be able to sort on this field, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort - isn't exist anymore in RavenDB v4.0. In previous versions it was instructing the index how to sort the results, numerically or lexicographically.

Reference: [1](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/Csharp/indexes/querying/sorting).

Store - would instruct the index to store the value in the index, so you won't need to reload the document from the storage in order to return this value.

Reference: [1](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/Csharp/studio/database/indexes/indexes-overview#indexed-data), [2](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/Csharp/studio/database/indexes/create-map-index#index-fields-options).